# Input textbox shortening on loading

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core, razor

I have a search box and a search icon. The search input box is shrinked on loading and the after the loading completed it is rendered as expected

**On Loading:**

[image]

**After Loading:**

[image]

I don't want the search icon to be outside the textbox it spoils the UX experience. Any idea on how to get it inside the search box even on loading.

Cshtml File:

```
   <form class="search header__search" action="/search.asp" method="get" data-component="search">
   <div class="col @(hasSidebar ? "col--medium-12 col--large-8" : "col--medium-12")">
   <div class="forum_search_wrapper search__wrapper">
      <input id="searchSite" class="search__input" type="text" name="searchterm" value="" placeholder="Search forums group and discussions" data-modal-focus data-search-input autocomplete="off">
      <label style="font-size:1px" for="searchSite"> . </label>
      <input type="hidden" name="searchcoll" value="Forum_Discussion">
      <button class="search__submit" type="submit">
      <i class="icon">
      @Html.UseSvgWithId("search")
      </i>
      <span class="search__label">Search</span>
      </button>
   </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

UseSvgWithId:

```
public static HtmlString UseSvgWithId(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string id) {
            var builder = new StringBuilder();
            builder.AppendLine("<svg role=\"presentation\">");
            builder.AppendLine($"<use xlink:href=\"#{id}\"></use>");
            builder.AppendLine("</svg>");

            var wc = htmlHelper.GetWorkContext();
            var svgRenderer = wc.Resolve<ILazySVGRenderer>();
            svgRenderer.Add(id);

            return new HtmlString(builder.ToString());
        }
```

css:

```
 .search__input {
            border: 1px solid transparent;
        }


.awesomplete,
.search .search__input {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Any hint on where i should start looking will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you use `<img src="xxx" />` to replace `@Html.UseSvgWithId("search")`?

Comment: @YiyiYou We are using the code to make svg rendering quick. I edited the function declaration in question.

Comment: It seem some class or css getting added after page load

Comment: @Satindersingh yes just identified that  we are adding a autocomplete class called awesomplete to provide auto-suggestion. It converts the textbox input into combobox. is there any way to load that class early on page load.

Comment: @devram  yes, by default adding that Class CSS property with existing element selector will auto fixed this issue, probably padding or margin is getting added, that you can add using !important